# Instrumentation test with toolbar: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation

Tags: java, android, toolbar, android-appcompat

When I'm trying to run instrumentation test on activity with toolbar (from support library) on Android 4.4.4 I'm getting error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:489)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v7/internal/widget/TintManager$ColorFilterLruCache
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.<clinit>(TintManager.java:54)
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getTintManager(TintTypedArray.java:192)
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:62)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:249)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:191)
... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:222)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:215)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:322)
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
... 31 more
```

The same test works fine on Android 5.1.0. Toolbar is displayed properly on both Android 4.4.4 and 5.1.0.

**MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.base_toolbar);
    }
}
```

**res/layout/activity_main.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/base_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivityTest.java**:

```
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mRule.launchActivity(new Intent());
    }

    @Test
    public void testAbc_testHasTextView() throws Exception {
        onView(withId(R.id.first_text_view)).perform(click());
    }
}
```

**app.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    ext.support_version = '22.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:rules:0.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }

    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}
```